# is there a way to change the position and rotation of a directionallighting after an if statement in ursina?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

i want to make it so when something is true then the directional lighting will have a different angle.
i tried something like this:

```
drlight = DirectionalLight(parent=pivot, y=3, z= -6, shadows=True, rotation=(0, 45, 
drlight2 = DirectionalLight(parent=pivot,y=100, z=120, shadows=True, rotation=(45, -45, 45))
drlight.enabled = True
drlight2.enabled = False
```

and then change it in some if:

```
    def input(self, key):
    if self.hovered:
        if key == 'left mouse down':
            if animloaded:
                drlight.enabled = True
                drlight.enabled = False
```

unfortunately it didnt work.
if anyone knows what to do
pls help

Comment: Instead of drlight.enabled = bool, can you experiment with drlight.ignore = bool. Just checking!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `drlight.enabled` to True and immediately back to False. Did you mean to disable drlight and enable drlight2?

Try this instead:

```py
drlight2.enabled = True
drlight.enabled = False
```

Comment: i think it was just a typo in this text but i tried to enable the other light at the start of this code but it still stays the same

Comment: is it even possible to enable and disable light? i know that i can destroy it with destroy()

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the right answer to my own question!
instead of swapping the lights
i have made the light as a class
and then change its position and rotation if something happened

```
class directlight1(DirectionalLight):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
        parent=pivot,
        y=3,
        z=-6,
        shadows=True,
        rotation=(0, 45, 30),

    )

if animloaded:
        
   directlight1.rotation = (45,-45,45)
   directlight1.y = 100
   directlight1.z = 120
```